# Concatenar elementos de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, algoritmos

Estoy tratando de concatenar un arreglo de strings:

```
const funcNames = ['paciente.obtener', 'paciente.buscar', 'paciente.contiene']
```

Este arreglo puede seguir creciendo...

Cada uno representa una función, por ejemplo: **paciente.obtener('expression')**
Lo que quiero hacer es recorrer la lista de strings y si el elemento tiene otro elemento adelante de su lista ponerlo dentro de la funcion y si es el ultimo dejarlo como **paciente.contiene(expresion)**

por ejemplo asi quedaria esta lista:

`paciente.obtener(paciente.buscar(paciente.contiene('expresion')))`

estoy intentando de esta manera:

```
funcNames.forEach((e, i) => {
      const demo = funcNames[i + 1] ? `${e}(${funcNames[i + 1]}(expresión))` : `${e}(expresión)`;
      console.log(demo);
    });
```

pero esto solo funciona con 2 y no se como concatenar con los demas para que vaya creciendo la "funcion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero usar un `for` invertido e ir agregando a un temporal o ejecutando una a una en su defecto, acá tienes un ejemplo:

```js
const funcNames = ['paciente.obtener', 'paciente.buscar', 'paciente.contiene']
    var tmp = "";
    for (var i = funcNames.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     tmp=funcNames[i]+"("+tmp+")";
        console.log(tmp);
    }
    console.log("Resultado final:" + tmp);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho!

Comment: Listo, un gusto.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando la misma idea de @JhoubertRincon de iterar desde el final, podemos usar `.reduceRigth()`:

```js
const funcNames = ['paciente.obtener', 'paciente.buscar', 'paciente.contiene'];

const str = funcNames.reduceRight((p, c) => `${c}(${p})`, "(expresion)");

console.log(str);
```